# iPhone default system keyboard color and style guide

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar, uicolor, uitoolbaritem

I created a custom UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItems as numbers and added it as an inputAccessoryView to the keyboard.

I need to make the UIToolbar match the keyboard color scheme and buttons exactly like standard iPhone keyboard numbers but I can't find anywhere what colors, size or style are used.

Outside of creating images that look like iPhone numbers, is there a way to create them programmatically with **system colors, style and size** so they match default keyboard buttons? Any guides/resources/examples on this?

Comment: As far as I know those methods are undocumented and using them get your app rejected if the reviewer noticed that you used them.